# What do you call "that" or "where"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, single-word-requests

For words that sit as placeholders for other words (and introduce subordinate clauses), is there a name?

For example,

> The quick brown fox **that** jumped over the lazy dog.
>
> The man **who** killed the cyclops.

What are these words called? (aside from "pronoun" or "demonstrative pronoun" for the case of terms like **this** and **that** [depending on usage])

They basically function as placeholders for other clauses or nouns.

Answer (score 7):

It could be a **[relative pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun)** if you consider the first part as a clause without the "This is":

> [This is] The quick brown fox that jumped over the lazy dog.
>    [This is] The man who killed the cyclops.

All the other [grammatical conjunctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_conjunction) (Coordinating conjunctions, Correlative conjunctions or Subordinating conjunctions) don't include 'who' or 'that'.

Comment: what might be interesting are the names we give to "there" and "where". As far as I know, "there" is usually called an adverb, but "where" an adverbial relative pronoun. This feels lacking, because there-where should be analogous to it-which (or that[dem.]-that[rel.] etc.). I propose that everyone call "there" an adverbial demonstrative pronoun from now on. What say you all?

Answer (score 3):

See the Wikipedia page on  [Restrictiveness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictiveness) 
:

> ...restrictive clauses are often headed by the *relative pronoun* "that" or by a zero relative pronoun

Thus, wiki says tis a relative pronoun.

Comment: Cool!  Thanks for the link! I have never heard of "zero relative pronouns" before, but that makes a lot of sense.